# Java error NULL

Tags: java, object, null

Hi I have got a Card class which has got a Team, and every Team can be different (Madrid, Barcelona, Juventus,....): When I do this:

```
    int q=3;
    Carta a = new Carta(3);
    System.out.println(a.getTeam().getNom());
```

It prints NULl, and I don't understand why. It should print "borussia.jpg"

```
   public class Carta{//

      //fcbarcelona 0, madrid 1, manutd 2,borussia,la //
      private int _identificador;
      private Team _p;

      Carta(int num){
          _identificador=num;
          switch( _identificador ){
            case 0: _p=new Barcelona();
            case 1: _p=new Madrid();
            case 2: _p=new ManUtd();
            case 3: _p=new Borussia();
            case 4: _p=new Chelsea();
            case 5: _p=new Arsenal();
            default: 
     }
     Team getTeam(){
         return _p;
     }
   }


public class Team {
private ImageIcon _imatgeDav;
private ImageIcon _imatgeDarrere;
private String _nom;

   Team(){}

   Team(String nom){
      _nom=nom;
      _imatgeDav = (new ImageIcon(nom));
      _imatgeDarrere = (new ImageIcon("revers_de_carta.jpg"));
   }
   ImageIcon getImatgeRevers(){
      return _imatgeDarrere;
   }
   ImageIcon getImatgeDavant(){
     return _imatgeDav;
  }
  String getNom(){
      return _nom;
  }
```

And here I have the differents teams:

```
    public class Madrid extends Personatge{
       String nom;
       public Madrid(){
         super("madrid.jpg");
         nom="madrid.jpg";
    }

    String getNom(){ return nom;}
}
```

Comment: Put `break` between your cases and check that `Arsenal` and other classes properly invokes a super constructor.

Comment: you need `break;` statements before every new `case:` in your switch

Answer (score 0):

2 thing in the code...

**1st you need a break in the switch case**

```
switch( _identificador ){
    case 0: 
        _p=new Barcelona();
        break;
    case 1: 
        _p=new Madrid();
        break;
    case 2: 
        _p=new ManUtd();
        break;
    case 3: 
        _p=new Borussia();
        break;
    case 4: 
        _p=new Chelsea();
        break;
    case 5:
        _p=new Arsenal();
    default:
}
```

2nd:
  you are using the wrong constructor by calling this:

```
new Borussia();
```

you need to call

```
new Borussia("Borussia-nom");
```

otherwise are all members of the class Team null referenced, and THAT will throw the exception when you call the `.getNom()` method of that object...